# What data structure to useto identify duplication with 3 variables?

Tags: .net, duplicates

I have a list of logs with 3 data points, which are date, username, and description.

For example:

5:01 - account1 - "passed"

5:01 - account2 - "failed"

5:02 - account2 - "passed"

5:03 - account2 - "passed"

I need to weed out duplication with +/-1 with same account name and description. The result that i expect based on above would be.

5:01 - account1 - "passed"

5:01 - account2 - "failed"

5:02 - account2 - "passed"

I tried using dictionary with time stamp as key but it won't work because there could be entries with same time stamp but different description. Using separate lists won't work because the data wouldn't be associated with one another.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is joining `username` and `desccription` strings (you may use a delimiter i.e. `username:desccription`) and use [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) as the data structure. `username:desccription` is the key and timestamps are the values here.

Another data structure would be `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> logs`